# session is not persisting.killed after redirect

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

Here is the code.If sign in it goes to `/dashboard` route. but after I go to other route `user session` is not persisting(by dd I found this).thanks in advance if you solve, I spent hours on this.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'],function(){

  Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
  })->name('home');

  Route::get('/dashboard' , [
    'uses' => 'UserController@GetDashboard',
    'as' => 'dashboard'
    ]);

  Route::post('/signin' , [
    'uses' => 'UserController@postSignin',
    'as' => 'signin'
    ]);
});
```

in my login controller

```
public function postSignin(Request $request)
  {
   if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request['email'],'password' =>       $request['password']])) {
  return redirect()->route('dashboard');
   }
  return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: Is this "other route" also included into `web` middleware?

Comment: yes,by code you can see

Comment: Check if your session config is not set to `array`. [See Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session)

Answer (score 0):

`$request` is an object, not an array. Try using `$request->get('email')`.

Comment: $request is an object, not an array. Check if `$request['email']` returns the correct data expected ? Else try using `$request->get('email')`

Comment: it works dude..after that only it could be redirected to /dashboard